# how drawing polygon at @here/maps-api-for-javascript

Tags: here-api

i want drawing  like google map 'DrawingManager',

It looks like：[drawing-control](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.7/api_reference/H.venues.Drawing.html)

```
var venuesProvider = new H.venues.Provider() // property 'venues' does not exist"@here/maps-api-for-javascript": "^1.30.9"
venuesService.loadVenue(VENUE_ID).then(venue => {`
venuesProvider.addVenue(venue);
venuesProvider.setActiveVenue(venue);

var drawingControl = new H.venues.ui.DrawingControl(venue);
ui.addControl('drawing-control', drawingControl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please use H.venues.ui.DrawingControl, This is the default drawing control component for venues. It will automatically track active venue :

```
H.venues.ui.DrawingControl
```

Example:

```js
var venuesProvider = new H.venues.Provider()

venuesService.loadVenue(VENUE_ID).then(venue => {
  venuesProvider.addVenue(venue);
  venuesProvider.setActiveVenue(venue);

  var drawingControl = new H.venues.ui.DrawingControl(venue);
  ui.addControl('drawing-control', drawingControl);
});
```

link : https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.7/api_reference/H.venues.ui.DrawingControl.html